# Honeycomb preview - can not install my app on emulator under Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

Just updated SDK and SDK tools in Eclipse, tried to run my application on Honeycomb and got the following:

```
[2011-01-28 00:22:12 - Androzic] Uploading Androzic.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-01-28 00:22:13 - Androzic] Installing Androzic.apk...
[2011-01-28 00:24:19 - Androzic] Failed to install Androzic.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2011-01-28 00:24:19 - Androzic] (null)
[2011-01-28 00:24:19 - Androzic] Failed to install Androzic.apk on device 'emulator-5554': EOF
[2011-01-28 00:24:19 - Androzic] com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: EOF
[2011-01-28 00:24:19 - Androzic] Launch canceled!
```

Other avd's are operating normally. Has anyone succeeded? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, I also get this error. Who can tell me how to solve it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Got the same message. Turned out the app was installed and I could launch it from the emulator Applications screen. The Honeycomb emulator is slow and my guess is the launch command times out before the emulator is ready.

Answer (score 7):

Even I was facing the same issue. Thanks to Overbeek for the hint,

Yes "Ton Van Overbeek" is right.Honeycomb emulator is slow that's why you will get error like

"Failed to install .apk on device 'emulator-5554': EOF
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: EOF
Launch canceled!"

Solution : Try to run the emulator separately from AVD Manager, Then after its up and running and you were able to see the Home screen, at that time you can Run you application from Eclipse IDE, targeting to this specific Emulator.Your app will run smoothly.

Answer (score 3):

I Got the same issue and i could resolve it.

It has created my program as an app in the emulator. So after this error comes you please directly go to the emulator and check for your app there and run it (click on it). It will run smoothly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue.

Turned out that I had not downloaded all the required packages in the AVD Manager.

Not sure if these are all required but this is what I downloaded to make it work:

- Android SDK Tools, rev 9
- SDK Platform Android Honeycomb
  Preview, rev 1
- SDK Platform Android 2.3.1, API 9,
  rev 2
- Samples for SDK API Honeycomb
  Preview, rev 1
- Samples for SDK API 9, rev 1
- Documentation for Android 'Honeycomb'
  Preview SDK, rev 1

Answer (score 0):

Increasing emulator ram size from 512 to 1024 solved it...

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue,

If your application is installed previously go to

Settings > Applications > Manage Applications > Uninstall your app from the emulator

Then

Right click on your project folder > run as > android application

If your app was not installed previously

Restart Eclipse and clean your project and run like before. In my case I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your system.. It will be solved. But it is temporary solution.