# android emulator cannot run my applications. its starts the emulator but doesnt run the program

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, adt

This is the output from the console window:

```
[2011-04-26 13:49:08 - Snake] ------------------------------

[2011-04-26 13:49:08 - Snake] Android Launch!

[2011-04-26 13:49:08 - Snake] adb is running normally.

[2011-04-26 13:49:08 - Snake] Performing com.example.android.snake.Snake activity launch

[2011-04-26 13:49:08 - Snake] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'avd_2.2'

[2011-04-26 13:49:08 - Snake] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'avd_2.2'

[2011-04-26 13:49:13 - Snake] New emulator found: emulator-5554

[2011-04-26 13:49:13 - Snake] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...

[2011-04-26 13:54:38 - Snake] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!

[2011-04-26 13:54:38 - Snake] Device API version is 8 (Android 2.2)

[2011-04-26 13:54:38 - Snake] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'

[2011-04-26 13:54:38 - Snake] Uploading Snake.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'

[2011-04-26 13:54:38 - Snake] Installing Snake.apk...

[2011-04-26 13:58:55 - Snake] Failed to install Snake.apk on device 'emulator-5554!

[2011-04-26 13:58:55 - Snake] (null)

[2011-04-26 13:59:01 - Snake] Failed to install Snake.apk on device 'emulator-5554': null

[2011-04-26 13:59:01 - Snake] com.android.ddmlib.InstallException

[2011-04-26 13:59:01 - Snake] Launch canceled!
```

From the beginning of the log to the end, you can see it takes about 10 minutes. Is it my computer or is launching an application on the emulator always so slow?

Comment: Which API you are using for Application?, Emulator is running on API-8 i.e. Android2.2

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the ADB connection timeout? The default value is 5000, changing this to 10000 gives more time to try and install the said package, it worked for me.
To do this go to window->Preferences->Android->DDMS.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your API level in default.properties?  Try adding `target=android-8` if you do not have it.

Also, as a side-note, it sounds like you are re-deploying the emulator every time you want to test.  You can start up the emulator once and then re-deploy the application to it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread .

[Honeycomb preview - can not install my app on emulator under Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822154/honeycomb-preview-can-not-install-my-app-on-emulator-under-eclipse)

Answer number 2 works well for me i.e. start AVD separately from AVD manager > start, when it shows Home then Run your application